# Program gives numbers instead of *

Tags: java, arrays, ascii, java.util.scanner

İ want to create an hangman game.Using single dimensional array.

İ first start to get the string than turn it into a char array and create a do while loop .İ created a variable  let say k i initiliazed it to 0 than start the loop if the given string has the char k will be increased by 1.When it becomes the size of string loop stop.İt is worked actually.The problem is when i want to show the which char is true and which isnt by *.İf it is true so string has it * will turn to given char.Problem is it doenst show the * and the true char instead it gives numbers.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] words = {"monkey","donkey","konkey","funkey","bonkey"};
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //random string from string array
    String str = randomString(words);
    //change string array to char array
    char[] word = str.toCharArray();

    int size = 0;


    boolean k = true;
    //Create the char array

    char[] array = new char[str.length()];
    //fill it with *
    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++) {
        array[i] ='*';
    }
    //check if given char is in the string
    do {
        System.out.print("enter the char");
        char given = input.next().charAt(0);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < word.length ; i++) {

            if(word[i] == given) {

                size++;
                char g = given;
                array[i] = g;

            }

            if(size == str.length()){
                k = false;
            }

            for(int e:array) {
                System.out.print(e);
            }

            }

    }while(k);

}//create randomString
  public static String randomString(String[] str) {

    int k =(int) (Math.random() * str.length);

    String strk = str[k];

    return strk;
}
```

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to debug a program.  if you are not using an IDE like eclipse, I would recommend installing it and read some tutorials.

Comment: İ am using eclipse.

Comment: explain the game well. i did not understand how it works.

Comment: İ create a array of string.And randomly choose one string.Ask the user give an letter.İf the string has the letter show the letter.Let say program choose monkey.firs it is like that ****** >m      given m than program shows m*****> j monkey doesnt have letter j   m******>o   mo*****  like that

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
for(int e:array) {
   System.out.print(e);
}
```

to this:

```
for(char e:array) {
   System.out.print(e);
}
```

you are implicitly casting char to int, which are printed as numbers and not characters.

Your code has many flaws, this is a revisioned version:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] words = {"monkey","donkey","konkey","funkey","bonkey"};
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //random string from string array
    String str = randomString(words);
    //change string array to char array
    char[] word = str.toCharArray();

    System.out.println("Picked " + str);
    int size = 0;

    boolean k = true;
    //Create the char array

    char[] array = new char[str.length()];
    //fill it with *
    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++) {
        array[i] ='*';
    }
    //check if given char is in the string
    do {
        System.out.print("enter the char: ");
        char given = input.next().charAt(0);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < word.length ; i++) {
            if(word[i] == given) {
                char g = given;
                //Check if the array[i] has been already replaced
                //If not increase the size
                if(array[i] == '*') size++;
                array[i] = g;
            }

            if(size == str.length()){
                k = false;
            }
        }

        for(char e:array) {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }while(k);
}

public static String randomString(String[] str) {

    int k = (int) (Math.random() * str.length);

    String strk = str[k];

    return strk;
}
```

Console output:

```
enter the char: k
***k**
enter the char: d
***k**
enter the char: o
*o*k**
enter the char: n
*onk**
enter the char: k
*onk**
enter the char: e
*onke*
enter the char: y
*onkey
enter the char: m
monkey
```

Comment: Why did you put an if statement to increase the size.İ remove it and everything same.And about my code my for loop was open i closed it.What other flaws.How can i improve the code can you give some advice.

Comment: the if statement before the increase of size is needed to check if that character has been already replaced. For example take the word "monkey", you insert 'k' and get - - - k - -  (I  used - instead of * ) and increase size from 0 to 1, then you insert 'k' again and get - - -k - - and increase size from 1 to 2, so now the size is 2 but you actually unlocked only one character! The if statement will prevent this behavior. About the for loop for printing the hiddent word, you should put it outside the other for loop, otherwise the word will be printed n times and that is not ok.

Comment: Or just `System.out.println(array)`